Error with Doctrine ORM attribute after converting code from annotation
I am upgrading from PHP7 to PHP8, ran my doctrine entities through Rector to update the annotations to attributes.  I'm getting the following error that I cannot get past:
Attribute "Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\OneToMany" cannot target method (allowed targets: property)

Here's my attribute code on the entity that I'm calling find() on so I'm assuming it's the entity causing the issue.
    #[OneToMany(targetEntity: TransactionReceiptCode::class, mappedBy: 'transaction', cascade: ['persist'])]
    protected  $rc_breakddown;

    #[OneToMany(targetEntity: TransactionFee::class, mappedBy: 'transaction', cascade: ['persist'])]
    protected  $fees;

Any information to track down the issue would be appreciated.

"so I'm assuming it's the entity causing the issue" Doesn't seem that's the case. The error message is telling you that you've got a OneToMany attribute on a method. That shouldn't be hard to find with something like grep -r -A1 OneToMany src

I have hundreds of entities.  The one entity I'm calling find() on that's in the backtrace of this error is the code above I posted.  All I'm saying is I assume it this class that's throwing the error.  But that doesn't help me with the error.  Everything looks correct when I compare it to the documentaiton.
